# C declaration syntax

Tags: c, sockets

I have a question about the syntax in the following code:

```
uint8_t in_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*) rp -> ai_addr) -> sin_addr.s_addr;
```

would the code above be the same as

```
struct sockaddr_in* some_name = rp -> ai_addr;
some_name -> sin_addr.s_addr;
```

If yes, why is it possible in `(struct sockaddr_in*) rp -> ai_addr` to declare it without a name for the structure?

Comment: Please pick up your text-book and refresh the sections about *casting*.

Comment: In the suggested code you still need a cast, `struct sockaddr_in* some_name = (struct sockaddr_in *) rp -> ai_addr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would the code above be the same as ...

Yes.

That's the base of inheritance in C, the first member of the `struct` and the `struct` itself are interchangeable because they share the same memory address, the compiler doesn't need a name but a type (basically the size and alignment), a simpler example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct base
{
    int a, b;
};

struct child
{
    struct base c;
    int d;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct child x = {{1, 2}, 3};

    // The compiler knows how to access member x.c.b due to the cast
    // (x and x.c shares the same memory address)
    printf("%d\n", ((struct base *)&x)->b);        // - Output: 2
    printf("%d\n", x.c.b); // Same than previous line - Output: 2
    return 0;
}
```